# Is there is any way to convert this FBV to CBV in polls tutorial of djangoTutorial?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have tried a few things but haven't gotten it working. I am a beginner.

```
def vote(request, question_id):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to convert this FBV to a CBV. The most basic one is you just copy paste the same logic inside the `get` or `post` function of a class based view and it will work just fine.

```py
from django.views import View

class PollDetailsView(View):
    def get(self, request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: A good explanation for the solution by n1ma can be found here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: Thanks but how to get this questionid ?  " question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)" into my class base views ?

Comment: i am using form here.
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

I have converted FBV to CBV for the Polls Application.
so now can someone here to guide me on how to use these form view methods instead of simple get and post?
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

My Project:https://github.com/moaazafzal/Polls-Django

class DetailFormClass(generic.View):
    template_name = "polls/details.html"

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    myquestion = Question.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
    # choice_form = ChoiceForm()
    # question_form=QuestionForm()
    #
    #
    context = {"question" : myquestion}
    return render(request, self.template_name,context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=kwargs['pk'])
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```